# Nifi Join two CSV flowfiles on specific common headers

Tags: hadoop, apache-nifi, hortonworks-data-platform

Trying to merge two incoming flowfiles in csv format and prepare a combined csv output with data from both based on some common header value.

**Need to join rows based on "creation_Date" and "Hour_of_Day" and merge the two flowfiles with a calculated difference between "source_count" and "hive_count"**. If INPUT_2 is missing a certain creation_date/Hour_of_day which INPUT_1 has *I need to include that as well* with maybe a "NOT AVAILABLE" under the "difference" header.

How can I achieve this in Nifi? Is there a way I can join using MergeContent and run a query on the output file for the difference generation?

Any help would be appreciated. :)

*SOURCE_INPUT_1*

```
creation_Date,Hour_of_day,source_count
2018-08-16,3,19934
2018-08-16,0,3278
2018-08-16,1,10680
2018-08-16,4,19705
2018-08-16,2,14199
2018-08-16,5,672
```

*SOURCE_INPUT_2*

```
creation_date,hour_of_day,hive_count
2018-08-16,0,3279
2018-08-16,1,10680
2018-08-16,3,19933
2018-08-16,2,14199
2018-08-16,4,19700
```

*COMBINED OUTPUT*

```
creation_Date,hour_of_day,source_count,hive_count,difference
2018-08-16,0,3278,3279,-1
2018-08-16,1,10680,10680,0
2018-08-16,2,14199,14199,0
2018-08-16,3,19934,19933,1
2018-08-16,4,19705,19700,5
2018-08-16,5,672,0,(NotAvailable)
```

Comment: NIFI is not an ETL like Talend. Trying to combine and merge different data flows is not a good idea/design.

Answer (score 3):

Apache NiFi doesn't typically do these kinds of streaming joins.

The joins it can do are more of a lookup join where one side of the data is fixed, and the other side comes from an incoming stream. This how the lookup services work and I believe there is a CSV lookup service.

The other option is to insert the data into a database, and then use ExecuteSQL to issue a SQL query that joins them together and writes the result out to a single flow file.

Lastly you could use a stream processing system like Spark, Flink, Storm, etc that all have true streaming joins.

MergeContent is meant to merge "like" data together, so if all the data was CSVs with the same columns, and you multiple flow files with that data, then you could merge them all into one big CSV.

Comment: Thanks for the insight @Bryan. It is actually a spin off from an existing process that I am trying to tap into to generate the combined output. Since the original process already exists in nifi, i was exploring options how to best extract it .I managed to generate csv out from the two different flows and now thinking of joining them in nifi itself before writing

Comment: Any way to use something similar to this? https://gist.github.com/ijokarumawak/7e20af1cd222fb2adf13acb2b0f46aed Only difference is I have mutually exclusive headers too that I want to include in the final output. Thanks in advance

Comment: Wow that is an interesting approach, Koji is the man! I think it will only work if you can somehow have each CSV have the super set columns, even if some columns are always empty

Answer (score -1):

@StrangerThinks This approach might help

use QueryRecord processor to join records and produce a row having different attributes in it:

```
select fa.t, fa.v a, fb.v b, fc.v c
 from (
   select t, v from FLOWFILE where m = 'a'
 ) fa
 left join (
   select t, v from FLOWFILE where m = 'b'
 ) fb on fa.t = fb.t
 left join (
   select t, v from FLOWFILE where m = 'c'
 ) fc on fa.t = fc.t
```

See More at 
https://gist.github.com/ijokarumawak/7e20af1cd222fb2adf13acb2b0f46aed